# Formula to work out 160th user?

Tags: c#

I have a table of users updated everyday - I want to get every 160th user.

I know I need to do a count to see if there are above 160 or 320 users so then I can take that user out but how would this formula work?

Do I divide the count of users by 160?

But how do I know whether its the 160th or 320th user is need?

This check is going to happen after every user signs up, so once the user is added to the db I need to see if they are a multiple of 160 then send them an email basically (db users can go over 165000).

Comment: whats your data access method?

Comment: What database backend are you using?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to check if they are 160th user **of that day**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way in knowing if the user is 160th.

```
if (userCount % 160 == 0)
        {
            //User is 160th user, or 320, 480 etc...
        }
```

This will validate if user is dividable by 160 with no decimals.
More info about modulo : http://www.dotnetperls.com/modulo

Comment: erm but 320 divided by 160 is 2 not 0 if thats what this means?

Comment: if you use X % Y == 0 where X is diviable by y, then this will be 0. This is just a simple way in determine if a number is diviable by any other given number. Updated the post with a link that will explain more about the usage of modulo

Answer (score 3):

Check if the devision by 160 equals to 0

**EDIT:** you can check whether it is 160th or 320th by using another counter like this:

```
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
     if(counter1 % 160 == 0)
{
    counter2++;
     //DO SOMETHING 
}
```

Now, `counter2` would be raised by 1 every 160 people.

Answer (score 3):

If your users table has integer ids, you can get users count with ids below or equal the current user's id and then check count % 160 == 0.

Answer (score 2):

If your database has an auto-incremented field (most databases tend to do that for their primary keys), you could execute a query where you check that `userID % 160 == 0`. This should return every 160th user starting from the 0th user.

Then, in your application, you could do `userId / 160` to see which is the 0th user, the 160th user, the 320th user, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
for (int i = 1; i < (int)(users.Count/160); i++)
{
    newUsers.Add(users[160 * i]);
}
```

... this is assuming you use a list, you haven't said. Your "db" should have similar methods to accomplish the same.

This will return the 160th, 320th etc. user.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that you want to scan a big amount of data (*db users can go over 165000*), it is probably not a good idea to query all users first, and then filter them at client side.

Better handle this at your database, like this:

```
SELECT R, userid FROM
(SELECT ROWNUM R, userid FROM (SELECT userid FROM users ORDER BY userid ))
WHERE MOD(R, 160) = 0
```

(This example is for Oracle, and there are probably more efficient ways to query this)

---

Sidenote:
Since you didn't give more information (the database you use, the layout of your table etc.), it's hard to come with a better answer. Also note that e.g. Sql Server has the abillity of sending emails, so you probably could use this feature without a client beeing involved.